# query will not order

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have this method

```
public function getArticles($order){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY :order");
        $stmt->bindParam('order',$order);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
```

that im calling like this

```
$articles->getArticles('created DESC');
```

but when i trying to do 'created ASC' it will not change the order?
i have tryed with two $vars and with `backtics` around the column, but i cant get it to work and i do not get any errors to work with it just pulls the rows in the same order every time.

Found the solution on https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

```
$orders  = ["name","price","qty"];
$key     = array_search($_GET['sort'], $orders);
$orderby = $orders[$key];
$direction = _GET['direction'] == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
$query   = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY $orderby $direction";
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as both "mysqli" and "pdo"? Those are two different animals.

Comment: This is clearly PDO.. I removed the *mysqli* tag.

Comment: That would be "both". The one that @FelippeDuarte used to flag it with, and the one I chose also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query uses a bind variable to name a column. You Can't Do That™.

Column names, including the ones in `ORDER BY` clauses, have to be  specified as part of the text of  the query.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i googled it and found the right way on https://phpdelusions.net/pdo.